# Identify jumps in electricity prices

Tags: time-series, structural-change

Have a time series that is a function of normally distributed variable and a non normal distributed variable. Now if I want to identify the normal distributed part, how would one proceed? I have looked around and I found that converting to log returns I am able to get the data in a good format. However when identifying the jumps in the log returns by 3 standard deviations it does not work because if I have two consecutive jumps or more the difference would not breach the error bound. How would one proceed to extract the jump part of the data?

Comment: How do you know you have a normally distributed variable? (Also is it conditionally normal, or is it the marginal distribution you're considering?)

Comment: I assume it based on reading about it( theory). I am considering marginal distribution.